# How to find average RGB values within a box?

Tags: python, colors, average, contour

[image: One of the images I am using]

I am trying to get the RGB average values for the area within the box. However, I cannot use things such as a contour, since some of the edges are cut off. I also cannot use fixed (x,y) points, since the "boxes" in other images are located in different position and may cut off certain edges. Is there a way to automatically determine what is "inside" the "box" as well as getting the average RGB values.

Comment: Try to use binarization, then, you can do some segmentation. You start in one corner and you attribuate a label to the pixel. Then you scan the neighborhood. If the pixel is the same binary color than the corner you attribuate the same label. You only scan neighbors of same binary color of your corner. You will have the region outside your shape which will be the group of same label pixels. Logically you will have the region inside your shape. The only problem is if your shape cut the whole width or length of your image, like if you have the top and bottom of your rectangle outside your image.

Comment: But you can check if you scanned the entire width and length. And if not, you redo the operation starting from another not already scanned corner (the opposite corner of your previous operation). If you have some hole in your contour, you can try to scan group of pixels like 4, 16, 32 (the higher it is, the higher you will tolerate some hole in your contour but you will be less accurate on your segmentation)